# PowerShell guessing game max number of guesses

Tags: powershell

Hi I have made a number guessing game, but I struggle to make the game stop after a x guesses.

```
$Number = (Get-Random 100) + 1
$Guess = 0
$count = 1

Write-Host "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100."

While ($Number -ne $Guess) {

Write-Host -NoNewline "What is the number? "
$Guess = [int] (Read-Host)

If ($Guess -gt $Number) { Write-Host "$Guess is too high." }
If ($Guess -lt $Number) { Write-Host "$Guess is too low." }   
If ($count -eq 7) {break}

}
Write-Host "Correct! $Number is the number I was thinking!"
```

Comment: Because you are not increasing the `$count` after each guess, hence it remains 1. Add `$count++` after `If ($count -eq 7) {break}`.

**But you would want to change the last `Write-Host` in case a person is not able to guess the number even after 7 attempts, you would want to display the appropriate message.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a variable into your `while` loop, named `$Tries` it increments itself by one everytime someone guesses a number, until it equals `10`, then the loop breaks.

Next to that, I've included the line that tells you that the number is correct within the loop and tell it to display the correct message and break the loop when the number is correct.

I had to include this in the loop because if I would just let it break the loop when `$Tries` was bigger than `10` it would still display the message stating that the number was correct.

```
$Number = (Get-Random 100) + 1
$Guess = 0
$Tries = 0

Write-Host "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100."

While ($Number -ne $Guess) {

Write-Host -NoNewline "What is the number? "
$Guess = [int] (Read-Host)

$Tries = $Tries + 1

If ($Tries -gt 10) { Write-Host "You have used all of your guesses, try again." ; break }
If ($Guess -gt $Number) { Write-Host "$Guess is too high." }
If ($Guess -lt $Number) { Write-Host "$Guess is too low." }   
If ($Guess -eq $Number) { Write-Host "Correct! $Number is the number I was thinking!" ; break}

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It work like a gem, I have also added a little tracker so you can see how many guesses you have used.

Comment: I have a problem, when I'm ad my 7th guess, and guess it right, it say that I have used all my guesses and shows me the correct number. The number that I have just guessed.

Comment: Change `$Tries -eq 7` to `$Tries -gt 7` (Assuming that you want to allow 7 guesses)